# Как цикл foreach поменять на обычный for?

Tags: java

Помогите разобраться. Как вот это

```
for(Car car : carPool)
```

поменять на

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<carPool.size(); i++)
{
    Car car = carPool.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Нужно поменять заголовок на понятный

Comment: @Doofy, поменял)

Comment: Угу, теперь каеф)

Comment: Я думал мне надо поменять, но я здесь тоже новенький и пользоваться сайтом еще не умею

Comment: @AK, ну я поправил... Хотя, если б я так сначала сделал, то ТС мог бы копирнуть и не получить то, что он хотел. В вопросе же было про i<10... Всем не угодил и в итоге получил самый заминусованный ответ за годы нахождения здесь(((

Comment: Странно как то ... а нулевой элемент коллекции как же? Если там индекс где то плюсуется на еденицу, то в условии нужно i<=carPool.size(), иначе один элемент не попадет в обход (первый лабо последний)

Comment: @RomanNovoselov, ТС изначально говорил, что надо foreach в for от 1 до 10. Ну я так и написал. А теперь у меня все спрашивают почему всё не так и ставят минусы( Исправил(

Comment: Я не минусил и вас не обвинял - это скорее вопрос к ТС, условие видел. Просто лучше поменять и в данном случае не вестись на поводу у ТС, так как это явно логическая ошибка, которая в будущем может завести в тупик других пользователей (как и ответ ниже, где вобще за пределы массива выпригиваешь - за что три голоса не понимаю)

Comment: @RomanNovoselov, я исходил из того, что таких вопросов тьма уже в интернете и не стал, засим, в детали вникать) Да и у всех есть возможность внести правку в вопрос/ответ и даже, в некоторых случаях, получить репутацию за это) А второй ответ да - странный. Там та же ссылка на элемент без переменной и тоже может у новичков вопросы вызвать

Answer (score 6):

Строго говоря, заменить `foreach` на доступ по индексу(порядковому номеру) можно не для всех коллекций, например `Set` не поддерживает такого доступа в принципе. С другой стороны нужно помнить, что некоторые коллекции, например `LinkedList` при индексном доступе тратят `O(n)` времени для доступа к `n`-му элементу коллекции! Итерировать коллекцию по индексу наподобие `carPool.get(i);` следует только, если коллекция поддерживает доступ по индексу за константное время (`O(1)`). Например классы, реализующие интерфейс `RandomAccess` предоставляют такой доступ.

Поэтому для задач, где есть необходимость знать индекс текущего элемента и не поддерживающих доступ по индексу или требующих линейного времени доступа к элементу по индексу, следует использовать итератор, а номер индекса считать в отдельной переменной, например вот так:

```
int i = 0;
for (Iterator<String> iter = collection.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); i++) {
    String element = iter.next();
    …
}
```

Comment: Логично, да. В .NET, кстати, есть интерфейс `IList<T>`, который можно проверить, чтобы узнать, реализует ли коллекция эффективный доступ по индексу. А в Java есть такое?

Comment: @VladD, да конечное есть такой RandomAccess - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html.

Comment: Ага, круто, спасибо.

Comment: @VladD все же прямым аналогом `IList<T>` является, внезапно, `List<T>`. RandomAccess - это лишь маркер что доступ по индексу является предпочтительным.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Однако [`LinkedList<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) имплементирует `List<T>`, что кажется немного странным. Мне казалось, что там эффективный доступ невозможен.

Comment: @VladD мне тоже кажется, что они это зря придумали